# In Elixir, why do I get '\t\n\v\f' when converting range to a list?

Tags: elixir

I when I use the code:

```
Enum.to_list 9..12
```

The following gets returned instead of a list:

```
'\t\n\v\f'
```

It seems to only happen with these specific numbers. Is this a bug? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe [Binaries, strings and char lists](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/binaries-strings-and-char-lists.html) in the getting-started documentation covers everything you need to understand what's going on here.

If all of the values in a list fall within the range of [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) code points, then IEx will display the result as a character list. `\t` is ASCII value 9, `\n` is 10, and so on.

Here's another example:

```
iex> Enum.to_list 65..70
'ABCDEF'
```

Comment: Ahh. That makes sense. I thought it was changing the datatypes in the list till I realized that I could access the values like any other numbers.